# Best way to disable and enable textboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple html code that does enable and disable some textboxes on button clicks. Below is my code.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.querySelector('#myText0').disabled = true;
  document.querySelector('#myText1').disabled = true;
  document.querySelector('#myText2').disabled = false;
  document.querySelector('#myText3').disabled = false;
  document.querySelector('#myText4').disabled = false;
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.querySelector('#myText0').disabled = false;
  document.querySelector('#myText1').disabled = false;
  document.querySelector('#myText2').disabled = true;
  document.querySelector('#myText3').disabled = true;
  document.querySelector('#myText4').disabled = true;
}


function myFunction3() {
  document.querySelectorAll("input").disabled = true;
  document.querySelector('#myText2').disabled = false;
  document.querySelector('#myText3').disabled = false;
  document.querySelector('#myText4').disabled = false;
}

function myFunction4() {
  document.querySelector("input").disabled = true;
  document.querySelector('#myText0').disabled = false;
  document.querySelector('#myText1').disabled = false;
}
```

```css
input{
  display:block;
  margin:0.85em
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText0" label="myText0" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText1" label="myText1" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText2" label="myText2" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText3" label="myText3" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText4" label="myText4" disabled>
<h2>
Manually Enabling text boxes
</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Disable 0,1 field</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Disable Rest field other than 0,1</button>
<br/>
<h2>
Disabling All initially and then enabling the required text boxes 
</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction3()">Disable 0,1 field</button>
<button onclick="myFunction4()">Disable Rest field other than 0,1</button>
```

I've got a total of 120 textboxes so I'm looking for a better way to do this. In my above code, the buttons under `Manually Enabling text boxes` are working as expected. Whereas, the other approach that I thought of under `Disabling All initially and then enabling the required text boxes` is not working as expected.
Also Please let me know if there is a better approach than what I've used as there are 120 textboxes and my approach is the most time-taking as I'm checking manually and my 2nd approach is saving 25% of the total time (considering 120 textboxes and the number of them to be disabled that were provided as part of my SRS).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple common methods that will 'cascade' the logic for you rather than defining each operation repeatedly. Take a look at the attached fiddle (*and its code snippet*)

```js
function myFunc1() {
  enableAll();
  disableTextbox('#myText0');
  disableTextbox('#myText1');
}

function myFunc2() {
  disableAll();
  enableTextbox('#myText0');
  enableTextbox('#myText1');
}

/* Common functions */

function disableAll() {
  disableTextbox('#myText0');
  disableTextbox('#myText1');
  disableTextbox('#myText2');
  disableTextbox('#myText3');
  disableTextbox('#myText4');
}

function enableAll() {
  enableTextbox('#myText0');
  enableTextbox('#myText1');
  enableTextbox('#myText2');
  enableTextbox('#myText3');
  enableTextbox('#myText4');
}

function disableTextbox(textboxName) {
  document.querySelector(textboxName).disabled = true;
}

function enableTextbox(textboxName) {
  document.querySelector(textboxName).disabled = false;
}

/* Common functions */
```

```css
input{
  display:block;
  margin:0.85em
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText0" label="myText0" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText1" label="myText1" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText2" label="myText2" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText3" label="myText3" disabled>
<input type="text" id="myText4" label="myText4" disabled>
<h1>Proper way to do it</h1>
<button onclick="myFunc1()">Disable 0,1 field</button>
<button onclick="myFunc2()">Disable Rest field other than 0,1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for, and for each "input type" or "class":

```js
function myFunction1() {
   //var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'); //use this or below
 var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class=ttt]');
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   inputs[i].disabled = false; // or true
    //inputs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
 function myFunction2() {
 //var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'); //use this or below
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[class=ttt]');
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
 inputs[i].disabled = true; // or false
 //inputs[i].style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

```css
input{
display:block;
margin: 0.85em
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText0" class="ttt" label="myText0" disabled>
 <input type="text" id="myText1" class="ttt" label="myText1" disabled>
 <input type="text" id="myText2" class="ttt" label="myText2" disabled>
 <input type="text" id="myText3" class="ttt" label="myText3" disabled>
 <input type="text" id="myText4" class="ttt" label="myText4" disabled>
 <h2>
  Manually Enabling text boxes
</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">enable all field</button>
 <button onclick="myFunction2()">disable all field</button>
```

Comment: You can shorten it with this for(let el of document.querySelectorAll('input.ttt')) el.disabled = true;

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to specify the reason for disabling in a class or even a data attribute. For simplicity let's use a class. So for example an input should be disabled because of any reason you give it a class (or data attr) with the value of the name of that reason. This will make your code very readable even **without reading over the javascript** files. And you will not write much of javascript at all.

That would make your elements that should be enabled together, together, and vice versa.

I would suggest this solution:

```js
function disable(className) {
  for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName(className)) {
    element.disabled = true;
  }
}

function enable(className) {
  for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName(className)) {
    element.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
input{
  display:block;
  margin:0.85em
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="reason1" label="myText0" disabled>
<input type="text" class="reason1" label="myText1" disabled>
<input type="text" class="reason2" label="myText2" disabled>
<input type="text" class="reason2" label="myText3" disabled>
<input type="text" class="reason2" label="myText4" disabled>
<h2>
  Manually Enabling text boxes
</h2>
<button onclick="disable('reason1'); enable('reason2')">Disable 0,1 field</button>
<button onclick="disable('reason2'); enable('reason1')">Disable Rest field other than 0,1</button>
<br />
<h2>
  Disabling All initially and then enabling the required text boxes
</h2>
<button onclick="disable('reason1'); enable('reason2')">Disable 0,1 field</button>
<button onclick="enable('reason1'); disable('reason2')">Disable Rest field other than 0,1</button>
```